# How to add custom field to the user profile according to its role in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users

i need to add some custom fields to the user. These fields are not the same for every user, but they vary according to their roles. How can i do that?

I saw that you can add some custom fields in the configuration menu but those cannot be differentiated according to the role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[User role field](http://drupal.org/project/user_role_field)** module allows you to specify role-specific fields. 
When creating a new field, you specify what roles this field is enabled for.

Fields are only visible and editable if a user has a specific role.

This role does not determine access controls for visible fields. 
You could use the [**Field Permissions**](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module for setting access controls.

More then 120 sites currently use this module.